# JSON MVC Chart not rendering in view

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, charts, controller

Not entirely sure what is going wrong with this as the Controller and View looks right. I can even get the JSON to return the data from the controller.

Example of JSON return:

```
[{"Expr1":134,"Computer_Brand":"Windows 10"}]
```

All I get is a blank page rendering with no chart or errors.
Really been racking my brain on this one. Any help would be really appreciated.

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
using expendit.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Syncfusion.Linq;
using Syncfusion.Olap.MDXQueryParser;

namespace expendit.Controllers
{
    public class Charts_ComputerOSController : Controller
    {
    private HAWKTRAINING_ROIEntities1 db = new HAWKTRAINING_ROIEntities1();

    // GET: Charts_ComputerOS


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public JsonResult GetPiechartJSON()
    {
        using (var db = new HAWKTRAINING_ROIEntities1())
        {
            var result = (from tags in db.Charts_ComputerOS
                          orderby tags.Computer_Brand ascending
                          select new { tags.Expr1,        tags.Computer_Brand }).ToList();
            //return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);





            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
    }
    public ContentResult GetDefect()
    {
        using (var db = new HAWKTRAINING_ROIEntities1())
        {

            var defect = (from d in db.Charts_ComputerOS

                          select new
                          {
                              d.Computer_Brand,
                              d.Expr1,

                          }).ToList();

            return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(defect));
        }
    }
    JsonSerializerSettings _jsonSetting = new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
}
}
```

**View**

```
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'GetPiechartJSON',
        data: '{}'
    }).done(function (response) {
        drawchart(response.d);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
        //for example purposes
        drawchart([{ "Expr1": 134, "Computer_Brand": "Windows 10" }]);

        //console.log(status, errorThrown);
    });

    function drawchart(dataValues) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Computer_Brand');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Expr1');

        for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
            data.addRow([dataValues[i].Computer_Brand, dataValues[i].Expr1]);
        }

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart  (document.getElementById('chartdiv'));
        chart.draw(data, {
            title: 'Computer OS Data',
            legend: {
                alignment: 'end',
                position: 'top'
            },
            fontsize: 14,
            chartArea: {
                width: '50%'
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you see any error in browser console?

Comment: No not from what I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you need to load google charts
not sure if you are already doing so,
but isn't shown in the code provided

see following working snippet,
try replacing your script with the following...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: 'GetPiechartJSON',
    data: '{}'
  }).done(function (response) {
    drawchart(response.d);
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
    //for example purposes
    drawchart([{"Expr1":134,"Computer_Brand":"Windows 10"}]);

    //console.log(status, errorThrown);
  });

  function drawchart(dataValues) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Computer_Brand');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Expr1');

    for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
      data.addRow([dataValues[i].Computer_Brand, dataValues[i].Expr1]);
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chartdiv'));
    chart.draw(data, {
      title: 'Computer OS Data',
      legend: {
        alignment: 'end',
        position: 'top'
      },
      fontsize: 14,
      chartArea: {
        width: '50%'
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Hi thank you. But this is really weird... I still get just a blank screen.

Comment: Hi Have got this working - thank you was a problem with the assemblies - now working.

Comment: Nope I was wrong. The Json data from the url is not populating the chart. Even though the url works to view it. The chart is using the example data only. Any ideas?

Comment: un-comment the line here --> `console.log(status, errorThrown);` and check the error in the console

Comment: Hi Never mind sorted it changed (response.d) to (response) and it works.